# Map thru nested JSON in Node ES6 not rendering expected formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

I am building a photo gallery using a nested JSON file. I want to map through it to create a nicely formatted JavaScript object or at least a smaller JSON file, containing only the text and image.url nodes. My approach has rendered a kind of weird object, not JSON, nor in the format the app wants.

The object that the application wants is like this

```
export const photos = [
    {
      src: "https:/app/uploads/medium__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b.jpg",
      width: 4,
      height: 4,
      title: "Gloria and Emilio together at the 1994   ."
    },
    {
      src: "https:/app/uploads/medium__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg",
      width: 4,
      height: 3,
      title: "Former  President and CEO Frances Preston and Adolfo Angel (2nd from left) with  guests at the 1994   ."
    },
    {
      src: "https:/app/uploads/medium_arrivals1_220673a90f.jpg",
      width: 3,
      height: 4,
      title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      src: "https:/app/uploads/medium_arrivals2_c5d28f3d2c.jpg",
      width: 4,
      height: 3,
      title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      src: "https:/app/uploads/medium_1_a9ea1a3a7a.jpg",
      width: 4,
      height: 3,
      title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      src: "https:/app/uploads/medium_2_e1cb163862.jpg",
      width: 4,
      height: 3,
      title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    }
  ];
```

Here is the source file

```
{
  "image_sets": [
    {
      "name": " 2022",
      "description": "<div class=\"en\">Moments from the 2020   </div>\n<div class=\"sp\">Spanish Subhead here about what comes next</div>",
      "meta_key": "22_gallery",
      "created_by": 1,
      "updated_by": 1,
      "created_at": "2022-02-27T21:09:24.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-03-09T20:10:08.000Z",
      "slide_show": null,
      "image_with_text": [
        {
          "text": "Gloria and Emilio  together at the 1994   .",
          "image": {
            "name": "_2021_gallery_Photo-5---1994_#0034.jpg",
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "Lorem ipsum",
            "width": 845,
            "height": 800,
            "formats": {
              "thumbnail": {
                "name": "thumbnail__2021_gallery_Photo-5---1994_#0034.jpg",
                "hash": "thumbnail__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 165,
                "height": 156,
                "size": 4.1,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/thumbnail__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b.jpg"
              },
              "medium": {
                "name": "medium__2021_gallery_Photo-5---1994_#0034.jpg",
                "hash": "medium__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 750,
                "height": 710,
                "size": 37.14,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/medium__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b.jpg"
              },
              "small": {
                "name": "small__2021_gallery_Photo-5---1994_#0034.jpg",
                "hash": "small__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 473,
                "size": 20.97,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/small__2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b.jpg"
              }
            },
            "url": "https://app/uploads/_2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b.jpg",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-03-23T22:50:53.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-23T22:50:53.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "text": "Former  President and CEO Frances Preston and Adolfo Angel (2nd from left) with  guests at the 1994   .</span>",
          "image": {
            "name": "_2021_gallery_Photo-2---1994_#0012.jpg",
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "Lorem ipsum",
            "width": 1150,
            "height": 800,
            "formats": {
              "thumbnail": {
                "name": "thumbnail__2021_gallery_Photo-2---1994_#0012.jpg",
                "hash": "thumbnail__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 224,
                "height": 156,
                "size": 9.34,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/thumbnail__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg"
              },
              "large": {
                "name": "large__2021_gallery_Photo-2---1994_#0012.jpg",
                "hash": "large__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 1000,
                "height": 696,
                "size": 95.48,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/large__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg"
              },
              "medium": {
                "name": "medium__2021_gallery_Photo-2---1994_#0012.jpg",
                "hash": "medium__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 750,
                "height": 522,
                "size": 63.83,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/medium__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg"
              },
              "small": {
                "name": "small__2021_gallery_Photo-2---1994_#0012.jpg",
                "hash": "small__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 348,
                "size": 33.53,
                "path": null,
                "url": "https://app/uploads/small__2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg"
              }
            },
            "url": "https://app/uploads/_2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-03-23T22:48:50.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-26T18:24:50.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code

```
const fs = require('fs')

// IMPORT DATA SET
const source = require('./source.json')

// GRAB ONLY DATA I WANT
const data = source.image_sets[0].image_with_text;
console.log('data is: ' + typeof(data)) // object

// LOOP THROUGH ARRAY
const mydata = data.map((item) => (
    `title: ${item.text}, src: ${item.image.url}, width: ${item.image.width}, height: ${item.image.height}`
    ))
console.log('mydata is: ' + typeof(mydata)) // object

// FORMAT JSON OR OBJ NOTATION
const mystring = JSON.stringify(mydata, null, 4)

console.log('mystring is: ' + typeof(mystring)) // string

// WRITE TO FILE
fs.writeFile('./user.js', mystring, 'utf-8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        console.log(mystring)
    }
})
```

It is profoundly disappointing that it is neither well formatted JSON or a JavaScript object that I can use. The stringify is not prettifying. Nor are the template literals forming multilines.

This is what I am getting

```
data is: object
mydata is: object
mystring is: string
[
    "title: Emilio  together at the 1994   ., src: https://app/uploads/_2021_gallery_Photo_5_1994_0034_7e3b73d19b.jpg, width: 845, height: 800",
    "title: Former  President and eston and Adold from left) with  guests at the 1994   .</span>, src: https://app/uploads/_2021_gallery_Photo_2_1994_0012_b7eebae562.jpg, width: 1150, height: 800"
]
```

Close, but no cigar. I have researched but without success. Thanks if you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to map the items to an object instead of a string:

```js
const mydata = source.image_sets[0].image_with_text.map((item) => ({
  title: item.text,
  src: item.image.url,
  width: item.image.width,
  height: item.image.height
}));

// FORMAT JSON OR OBJ NOTATION
const mystring = JSON.stringify(mydata, null, 4)

// WRITE TO FILE
fs.writeFileSync('./user.js', `export const photos = ${mystring};`, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle. That was concise and I gained a clearer understand of JS as a result.